# AS3 Concatenating Reference Not Working

Tags: actionscript-3, concatenation

I'm struggling to concatenate a reference to a variable from a XML document. I'm trying to get:

```
chat_History.Msg.chatMessage1, chat_History.Msg.chatMessage2, chat_History.Msg.chatMessage3
```

It's instead over-riding the reference and turning into the value '0', '1', '2'. My code:

```
    public function onReceivedChatData(Event:LoaderEvent)
{
    var raw_user_info = LoaderMax.getContent("chatHistory");
    var chat_History:XML = XML(raw_user_info);

    if (chat_History.Msg) 
    {
        trace("ReceivedChatData");
        trace(chat_History);                        

        for (var i:int = 0; i < int(chat_History.chatLength); i++)
        {
            var chatString:String = chat_History.Msg.chatMessage;
            chatString += i.toString();

            shopchatbox.shop_chat_window.text = shopchatbox.shop_chat_window.text + "\n" + chatString;
            shopchatwidebox.shop_chat_window.text = shopchatwidebox.shop_chat_window.text + "\n" + chatString;

        }
    }
    else
    {
        trace("chat_History XML Does Not Exist!!! Noooo :( ");
        trace(chat_History);
    }
}
```

The chatLength is 3, and it's calling the for statement 3 times correctly, however chatString isn't referencing it's variable (a string) correctly and only appears as '0', '1', '2'. I'm guessing I'm not concatenating this right and that's the problem, but I'm not sure how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the relevant XML?

Answer (score 0):

`chatString += i.toString();`

That's going to give you the indexes 0, 1, 2. `i` just stores increments for iteration. Not the values from `chat_History.Msg.chatMessage` So you're adding `i` onto the *content* of `chatString`, not setting the variable name.

```
var chatString:String = chat_History.Msg.chatMessage;
chatString += i.toString();
```

Your code here says, take `chatString`, and set it to the value `chat_History.Msg.chatMessage`, then concatenate `i` as a `String` onto the content of `chatString`

If you wanted to access your variables by a variable name, I believe you'd do something like this;

```
var chatString:String = chat_History.Msg["chatMessage"+ String(i+1)];
```

So `i+1` = 1, 2, 3. Which should mean you're accessing `chat_History.Msg.chatMessage1`, `chat_History.Msg.chatMessage2` and `chat_History.Msg.chatMessage3`

Remove the line;

```
chatString += i.toString();
```

I'm afraid I can't test this as I don't have the XML code, but hopefully that gives you a general idea. I'm not 100% sure I've got calling a variable by a variable name correct, but it is possible to call a variable by a string name.

Edit:

After doing a little testing, the syntax appears to be correct, so that should get you the values from `chat_History.Msg`